# Firebase Cloud Messaging en Background con sonido personalizado

Tags: flutter, dart, fcm

¿Alguien ha trabajado con FCM?
¿Quién logró personalizar el sonido del push notifications en background?
O ¿quién logró que al llegar la notificación, *no suene*?

Lo que necesito es que no se reproduzca el sonido cuando llega la notificación (dejar en mudo o vibrador el dispositivo no es opción).

```
// esto solo funciona sobre IOS segun la documentación
FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
alert: false,
badge: false,
sound: false,
);
```

Algo así me gustaría en Android.

También en la documentación se menciona hacer uso del paquete de local notifications para recibir en foreground, pero estoy batallando con background.

La documentación consultada:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final sí era tema de configuración del Android.

Pasos a seguir:

1.- Agregar en `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` dentro de las etiquetas `<application> ... </application>`

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" 
/>
```

2.- Crear en `android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml` y copiar lo siguiente:

```xml
< resources>

    <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">ARoSistemas</string>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_name" translatable="true">ARoSistemas</string>

< /resources>
```

si ya se tiene, solo agregar las etiquetas.

3.- Agregar el sonido que se guste en formato mp3 en la carpeta `android\app\src\main\res\raw\`

4.- Agregar en el payload de FCM:

```
"sound": "mi_sonido",
"_channel_id":"ARoSistemas",
```

y ¡*voilá*! Funcionó a la perfección...

Salió un detalle que al abrir la app, suena el predeterminado una vez.

Documentos oficiales consultados:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Revisaré lo que comenta, muchas gracias.